# Configure keepalived for services (NodePort) on kubernates

Tags: kubernetes, keepalived

I have a k8s cluster which contains 2 nodes. And in the cluster I deployed 2 pods for the same application. Due to some reason I have to deploy a service (NodePort IP) for each pod, so totally I have 2 services the application, for example the service NodePort IP is 192.142.1.11 and 192.142.1.12. And use these 2 ips I can access the application from any node.

Now I am going to use keepalived to set up HA for the application. So:

1. What's the best practice to install the keepalived service? On each k8s node or deploy it as pod?
2. How to configure the `interface` in the **keepalived.conf** file? You know the NodePort ips are configured on *kube-ipvs0* interface created by k8s and its status is down. Seems it cannot be used as the interface in keepalived.conf. Should I use the Node external interface if I start keepalived service on each node?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your final goal is masters HA / users  service load balancing in on-prem environment, then you can take a look on this two project:

[Kubevip](https://kube-vip.io/): can do both (HA masters + LoadBalancer type for user workload).

[Metallb](https://github.com/metallb/metallb):
user workload LoadBalancer